# Greenplum coredump when exec query cmd

Tags: coredump, greenplum

I am using Greenplum 5.0

When I execute a query, I will cause core, but I can connect and execute some ddl statements.

This is the query I run:

```
db_immsg=# select * from tbl_immsg;

server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

log

```
2019-05-05 18:46:24.622419 CST,,,p30204,th-1140861120,,,,0,,,seg-1,,,,,"LOG","00000","3rd party error log:
postgres:  5432, higw db_immsg 183.36.111.89(22814) con96 cmd1 SELECT: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libnaucrates.so.3: undefin
ed symbol: _ZN5gpopt15CPredicateUtils28FIdentCompareConstIgnoreCastEPNS_11CExpressionENS_9COperator11EOperatorIdE",,,,,,,,"SysLoggerM
ain","syslogger.c",618,
```

stack

```
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `postgres:  5432, gpadmin db_immsg 183.36.111.89(52298) con30 cmd1 SELECT      '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f72b95f7b7b in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f72b95f7b7b in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000092516b in StandardHandlerForSigillSigsegvSigbus_OnMainThread ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x0000000000a69635 in gpdxl::CTranslatorUtils::FDuplicateSensitiveMotion(gpdxl::CDXLPhysicalMotion*) ()
#4  0x0000000000a922b9 in gpdxl::CTranslatorDXLToPlStmt::PplanTranslateDXLMotion(gpdxl::CDXLNode const*, gpdxl::CDXLTranslateContext*, Plan*, gpos::CDynamicPtrArray<gpdxl::CDXLTranslateContext const, &(void gpos::CleanupNULL<gpdxl::CDXLTranslateContext const>(gpdxl::CDXLTranslateContext const*))>*) ()
#5  0x0000000000a86c2b in gpdxl::CTranslatorDXLToPlStmt::PplstmtFromDXL(gpdxl::CDXLNode const*, bool) ()
#6  0x0000000000a972ae in COptTasks::PvOptimizeTask(void*) ()
#7  0x00007f72babbee90 in gpos::CTask::Execute() () from /usr/local/lib/libgpos.so.3
#8  0x00007f72babc1188 in gpos::CWorker::Execute(gpos::CTask*) () from /usr/local/lib/libgpos.so.3
#9  0x00007f72babbde11 in gpos::CAutoTaskProxy::Execute(gpos::CTask*) () from /usr/local/lib/libgpos.so.3
#10 0x00007f72babacf16 in gpos_exec () from /usr/local/lib/libgpos.so.3
#11 0x0000000000a92d73 in COptTasks::Execute(void* (*)(void*), void*) ()
#12 0x0000000000a9405f in COptTasks::PplstmtOptimize(Query*, SOptContext*, bool*) ()
#13 0x0000000000a98d64 in PplstmtOptimize ()
#14 0x00000000007611f1 in planner ()
#15 0x000000000080356c in pg_plan_queries.constprop.12 ()
#16 0x000000000080529a in exec_simple_query ()
#17 0x000000000080770e in PostgresMain ()
#18 0x00000000007a9ed7 in ServerLoop ()
#19 0x00000000007ac014 in PostmasterMain ()
#20 0x00000000004c2c8b in main ()
```

I am a newcomer to the postgres. but i get the result of gpstate like this

```
gpadmin@mdw:~/greenplum/bin$ ./gpstate 
20190506:11:49:59:000536 gpstate:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting gpstate with args: 
20190506:11:49:59:000536 gpstate:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-local Greenplum Version: 'postgres (Greenplum Database) 5.0.0-alpha build dev'
20190506:11:49:59:000536 gpstate:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-master Greenplum Version: 'PostgreSQL 8.3.23 (Greenplum Database 5.0.0-alpha build dev) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.9.4 compiled on Sep  8 2017 00:02:21'
20190506:11:49:59:000536 gpstate:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Obtaining Segment details from master...
20190506:11:49:59:000536 gpstate:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Gathering data from segments...
```

Comment: `COptTasks::PplstmtOptimize(Query*, SOptContext*, bool*)` This looks like C++, so it cannot be original Postgres. Also: 8.3 ?

Comment: gpstate get   : local Greenplum Version: 'postgres (Greenplum Database) 5.0.0-alpha build dev'
-master Greenplum Version: 'PostgreSQL 8.3.23 (Greenplum Database 5.0.0-alpha build dev) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.9.4 compiled on Sep  8 2017 00:02:21'
2019

Comment: You are using version 5.0.0-alpha.  You should upgrade to the latest binaries and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: 5.0.0-alpha is very old. The ubuntu support discussion was later than 5.0.0-alpha.